# RichEditor Snippets and Nested Relations Rendering

Tags: nested, relationship, octobercms, froala

- OctoberCMS Build: 469
- PHP Version: 7.3
- Database Engine: MySQL
- Plugins Installed: Rainlab.Builder, Rainlab.Translate, Inetis.RichEditorSnippets, Rainlab.Pages

#### Description:

I have followed the tutorial to make List and Form with nested Relations (https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-21).

I open a model, and inside this model, i have a relation that have many relations like below :

-- Residence

--- Pages

---- Sections

In the "Section" popup, i display a richeditor, with snippets. But when i click on the snippet to open and edit properties, it can't focus the input.

I have search a long time in the source code of all OctoberCms, but i did not find anything.
After many tries, i have found that if in the browser inspector, i delete formPopups, the focus enables.

Here is an example of what i have actually.
[image: octobercms-snippets]

Here is an example where i delete the second popup in the browser inspector
[image: octobercms-snippets-2]

Does someone already had this issue ? Is there any fix for ?

EDIT :

#### Steps to reproduce

To help you to reproduce this,
you need to make 3 models with those fields :

**1. Residence** - *fields.yaml*

```yaml
fields:
    name:
        label: Residence
        span: left
        required: 1
        type: text
    pages:
        type: partial
        path: pages
    home_content:
        label: 'Residence Content'
        size: large
        span: full
        type: richeditor
```

**2. Page** - *fields.yaml*

```yaml
fields:
    title:
        label: Titre
        span: left
        required: 1
        type: text
    sections:
        span: full
        path: pages_sections
        type: partial
```

**3. Section** - *fields.yaml*

```yaml
fields:
    title:
        label: Title
        span: left
        required: 1
        type: text
    content:
        label: Content
        size: ''
        span: full
        required: 1
        type: richeditor
```

And you need to create relations in your models :

1. *Residence.php*

```php
    public $hasMany = [
        'pages' => [
            'Author\Plugin\Models\Page'
        ]
    ];
```

1. *Page.php*

```php
    public $hasMany = [
        'sections' => [
            'Author\Plugin\Models\Section'
        ]
    ];
```

Then you need to follow the tutorial on Making form with nested relations (https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-21) to be able to open the relation between Page and Section inside the Residence Form.

Do not hesitate to ask me for more informations,

Best,

Comment: hmm can you share minimal code of your plugin, specific to that part, maybe we can debug and help you, find an email from my profile in case

Comment: Hi @HardikSatasiya , unfortunately, this behavior isn't relative on my plugin, i just use OctoberCMS core RichEditor and Snippets from RainLab.Pages plugin.

Comment: can you check if it also happens if we do not nest things?

Comment: if i use only the controller of the relation, it works normally. but i can't use it like this, cause i have hundreds of sections with the same name.

Comment: hmm, I guess then its hassle to reproduce it locally in our machines

Comment: @HardikSatasiya i've updated my question with some code to help you reproduce. FYI,i have this bug on local and production. Please tell me if you need more information, and if you need to see it live, i can show you on the OctoberCMS discord or Slack.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed description, once I get time I will check it out and give you a solution if possible :)